# How to display the last four digit of any input number masking the rest with a string of stars?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a program to mask the first digits of any input numbers by a string of stars and displaying only the last four digits. I would like my output to be similar to a transaction receipt that only prints the last four digits of a customer's credit card masking the first digits with some stars.
My program below only prints the last four omitting the stars. How could I fix the issue?

```js
function padFunction(number){
   let string = String(number)
   let sliced = string.slice(-4); 
   let mask   = String(sliced).padStart(number.length, "*")
   return mask;
  }
  console.log(padFunction(653214987525));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only issue is you meant `string.length`, not `number.length` when generating the star padding.

```js
function padFunction(number) {
  let string = String(number)
  let sliced = string.slice(-4); 
  let mask = String(sliced).padStart(string.length, "*")
  return mask;
}
console.log(padFunction(653214987525));
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that `sliced` will be a string, so there's no need to create a string before padding it. And `String.padStart` is not well supported, `String.repeat` has better support, but still not great.

Comment: 10/2023 update - padStart 96% coverage in browsers https://caniuse.com/?search=padstart